# Make a particular cell in Excel, readonly without acquiring protection on the whole sheet

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I have a module of application where an excel sheet is being exported from my application. I have to make a few columns uneditable or readonly in the sheet.
Several websites have said first I make it locked and then protect the whole sheet. Is there any method that I can make few cells readonly and not make the sheet protected??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using events `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

```
Public oldValue             ' Save the current value of the cel
Public saveValue As Boolean ' Save the state of updating the cell value

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' If an update is in progress, don't do anything
    If saveValue Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Set the update is in progress
    saveValue = True

    ' Here you compare the range updated with protected range (here Sheet1!H1)
    ' if range are the same
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Address Then
        ' Restore the range with the oldValue
        Target = oldValue
    End If

    ' control an other Range
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3").Address Then
        Target = oldValue
    End If

    ' Unset the state "an update is in progress"
    saveValue = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Save the oldValue if no update is in progress
    If Not saveValue Then
        oldValue = Target
    End If
End Sub
```